# Is it possible to force the opening `sln`-file with particular `vssettings`-file always?

Tags: visual-studio, vssettings

I use Git for my Visual Studio solutions. Also I use my individual settings for this IDE text editors. But other programmers have their preferences for the same settings. Therefore often if they press the `Ctrl + K + D` keys in the Visual Studio text editor then the text formatting will be changed and when they push the changes back to Git then I'll see many changes which contradict to my formatting settings. *Git will highlight it as change in code*. Later, if I will press the `Ctrl + K + D` keys then that programmers will get the same problem when they pull the repository to their local machines...

I.e. it is a vicious circle...

So, the problem is what we use different settings of IDE text editors. I can export my settings to the `vssettings`-file and place it in my solution directory (and to include this file into my Git-repository, of course).

Is it possible to force Visual Studio that each time, when IDE opens my `sln`-file (i.e. the solution) then it is necessary to use the `vssettings`-file *from the same directory* if such `vssettings`-file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it cannot be done without an extension.
A quick web search revealed this extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/410e9b9f-65f3-4495-b68e-15567e543c58

You would have to force the other developers to use it, too.